# Core data migration issue - Its crashing the application

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

I have used cord data in my application, its already uploaded and live on app store. Now I want to upload a new version with some changes in core data but application is crashing with following error -

```
reason = "Can't find model for source store";
```

My code is already having atomic migration here is the code

```
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                               initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

if(![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                              configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error])
```

I read the apple documentation and try to use

```
- (BOOL)migrateStore:(NSURL *)storeURL toVersionTwoStore:(NSURL *)dstStoreURL error:(NSError **)outError
```

But how I find destination and source StoreURL here? From where should I call this method? And how?

Please give some suggestions to solve this problem.

Comment: did you create the destination model(Derived from the source model)?  Seems model is not tagged properly.
FYR - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-migrations--cms-21844

Comment: Awesome.... Perfectly work... Tutorial is nice and solved the problem with the help of same.  Thank you Ganapathy.. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved this problem with the help of this tutorial.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-migrations--cms-21844

Worth reading...  :) Enjoy